# SSH tunneling and NETCAT to access specific service on server

Tags: ssh, netcat

I am aware that we can create a bidirectional pipe using SSH and NETCAT:
https://www.frameloss.org/2013/12/14/wicked-cool-reverse-proxy-with-bash-and-netcat/

What I would like to do is for a client to access one and only one specific service on a server, nothing else, and pipe it using SSH & NETCAT.

I do not want the client to explicitly specify a random command because I want to keep his access to the server minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Please nevermind. I already found the solution I was looking for and I don't even need NETCAT:
https://research.kudelskisecurity.com/2013/05/14/restrict-ssh-logins-to-a-single-command/